# Reconstruct an array of objects in javascript that contains nested arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm struggling of coping with an issue here.
lets suppose I have an array of objects like this:

```
[
 {name:Alex, products: [{type: 1, code: 1213}, {type: 2, code: 2312}]},
 {name:Alex, products: [{type: 1, code: 1213}, {type: 2, code: 2312}]}
]
```

I would like somehow to reconstruct my object to be something like this:

```
[
 {name:Alex, products: [{name:Alex, type: 1, code: 1213}, {name:Alex, type: 2, code: 2312}]},
 {name:Alex, products: [{{name:Alex, type: 1, code: 1213}, {{name:Alex, type: 2, code: 2312}]}
]
```

so each nested array contains the name. Is that possible in javascript?

Comment: `Is it possible in javascript?`  Yes.

Comment: Could you so me the way to do this?

Comment: See below for spoon feeding, where you get to brush up on your copy/paste skills.  Alternatively, look __[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)__ and learn how to do it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map()` method with spread syntax in object to create new array with updated objects and keep original data.

```js
const data = [
 {name:'Alex', products: [{type: 1, code: 1213}, {type: 2, code: 2312}]},
 {name:'Alex', products: [{type: 1, code: 1213}, {type: 2, code: 2312}]}
]

const result = data.map(e => ({
  ...e,
  products: e.products.map(p => {
    return {...p, name: e.name}
  })
}))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want somehow to **reconstruct** my object so as to be something like
>   this:

Use map

```
arr.map( s => (s.products.map( i => (i.name = s.name, i) ), s) );
```

**Demo**

```js
var arr = [{
    name: "Alex",
    products: [{
      type: 1,
      code: 1213
    }, {
      type: 2,
      code: 2312
    }]
  },
  {
    name: "Alex",
    products: [{
      type: 1,
      code: 1213
    }, {
      type: 2,
      code: 2312
    }]
  }
]
var output = arr.map(s => (s.products.map(i => (i.name = s.name, i)), s));

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Interestingly this is the only correct answer, as rightly you have noticed the word `reconstruct`, all other answer are assuming the OP wanted copy.

Answer (score 1):

You could create new array/objects with [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

```js
var data = [{ name: 'Alex', products: [{ type: 1, code: 1213 }, { type: 2, code: 2312 }] }, { name: 'Alex', products: [{ type: 1, code: 1213 }, { type: 2, code: 2312 }] }],
    converted = data.map(o => Object.assign(
        {},
        o,
        { products: o.products.map(p => Object.assign({ name: o.name }, p)) }
    ));
    
console.log(converted);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) calls with [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to create the new array without changing the original data:

```js
const data = [{"name":"Alex","products":[{"type":1,"code":1213},{"type":2,"code":2312}]},{"name":"Alex","products":[{"type":1,"code":1213},{"type":2,"code":2312}]}]

const result = data.map((o) => Object.assign({}, o, {
  products: o.products.map((p) => Object.assign({ name: o.name }, p))
}))

console.log(result)
```

If you just want to change (mutate) the current array, use nested [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) calls:

```js
const data = [{"name":"Alex","products":[{"type":1,"code":1213},{"type":2,"code":2312}]},{"name":"Alex","products":[{"type":1,"code":1213},{"type":2,"code":2312}]}]

data.forEach((o) => o.products.forEach((p) => p.name = o.name));

console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have typo in name property.Alex should be 'Alex' (string).You can get help from two array methods. [**`Array.prototype.map()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [**`Array.prototype.forEach()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to achieve your goal

```
var initialArr = [
 {name:'Alex1', products: [{type: 1, code: 1213}, {type: 2, code: 2312}]},
 {name:'Alex2', products: [{type: 1, code: 1213}, {type: 2, code: 2312}]}
]

var newArr = initialArr.map(function(elem){
    elem.products.forEach(function(obj){
        obj.name = this.name
    },elem)
    return elem
})
console.log(newArr)
```